# How to Pass Values from DropdownList and Textbox to a Classic ASP Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, query-string

I'm working with a site originally coded in classic ASP and slowly being migrated to ASP.NET.  The search functionality on the default.aspx page needs to pass values to the itemsearch.asp page.  Specifically, I need to pass the ddlCat.selectedvalue and txtSearch.text values to the itemsearch.asp page so that results can be rendered.

What changes must I make to the itemsearch.asp page to accomodate this incoming set of values?  Likewise, what must be done in the default.aspx.cs to ensure these values are passed and that the itemsearch.asp page is called correctly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same way: post form fields. Just match up the expected field names.

Comment: Pretty sure this is right. Caveat being that any more advanced functionality like Sessions won't pass between the two pages.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751398/is-it-possible-to-share-session-state-between-asp-classic-and-asp-net