# Session FROM ASP.NET to classic asp

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic

I have an old system that was developed, not by me, in classic ASP.
I have a new system, developed by me in ASP.NET

How can I pass a session variable (not complex types, just a simple string or int) TO that classic ASP page? I don't need anything back from it.

To add a spanner to the works - how can I do the "hand off" or transfer if the classic ASP site is on a different domain?

Update: 
Cannot use the option of passing items via querystring OR storing it in a DB and letting the classic ASP read it from the DB.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share session state between asp classic and asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751398/is-it-possible-to-share-session-state-between-asp-classic-and-asp-net)

Comment: Is using the querystring out of the question?

Comment: correct andorbal - using the QS is out of the question because the old classic asp system checks the session for a value and if it does not exist it does something funky... dont want it to go through the funky section :)

Comment: I would encrypt it in the query string and modify the session 'funky' area in the asp site.  You will not be able to pass the session object to classic asp, especially on a different domain.  Every other way to do this is a 'hack' and it not very secure, hence why you should encrypt it.

Comment: yeh. ive had to revert to this.... eesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a classic asp page that sets session variables out of e.g. post parameters.

then call that classic asp page from your asp.net page.

example (not complete) session.asp:

```
if session("userIsloggedIn") = true and request.form("act") = "setSessionVar" then
    session(request.form("name")) = request.form("value")
end if
```

of course this is some kind of hack but we are talking about classic asp...

Answer (score 0):

I had a different direction.  I exchanged the session states via a cookie.  Adding these methods. So now instead of calling Session directly, I use these methods instead.

ASP.NET

```
 public static void AddSessionCookie(string key, string value)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SessionCookie"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("SessionCookie");
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
        cookie[key] = value;
    }
    public static string GetSessionCookie(string key)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null)
            return string.Empty;

        string cook = HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cook))
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SessionCookie"];
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("SessionCookie");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            if (cookie != null)
                cookie[key] = cook;

            return cook;
        }
        return cook;
    }
```

Then for Classic

```
Function AddSessionCookie(key, value)

    Response.Cookies("SessionCookie")(key)= value
Response.Cookies("SessionCookie").Expires = DATE + 1
Session(key) = value

End Function

  Function GetSessionCookie(key)

If Session(key) <> "" Then
Response.Write(Session(key))
ELSEIF Response.Cookies("SessionCookie")(key) <> "" THEN
Session(key)=Response.Cookies("SessionCookie")(key)
Set GetSessionCookie = Session(key)
End If
End Function
```