# Sharing sessions between Flask and ASP Classic

Tags: cookies, flask, asp-classic, session-cookies, flask-login

We are in the process of porting to Flask a POS app written in ASP Classic. We want to roll the pages out incrementally so that some pages use Flask while some pages use ASP Classic.

The hurdle is sharing sharing sessions between the two, which includes sharing the authentication variables. I have two questions about this:

1. Does the right approach entail sharing sessions in the form of cookies?
2. If so, how do I accomplish cookie-based authentication on Flask so that I can get the user variables with the cookies I send from ASP Classic?

Comment: I know nothing about Flask other than that it's written in Python.  There are quite a few questions here about sharing session variables between Classic ASP and ASP.net.  The issue is essentially the same, the two sets of pages can't see each other's session data. There's no "right" approach.  Solutions vary from passing variables client side with ajax or invisible iframes, to writing them to a database where more security is needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751398/is-it-possible-to-share-session-state-between-asp-classic-and-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you would be exposing users to a security concern called session hijacking.  My knowledge of Flask is minimal, but I do not think it can query session data from ASP, so you would have to pass the session's data to Flask.