# Possible ways to use JWT token authentication to access another domain/web application developed in VB.Net 2 webforms and MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, jwt

My sincere apologies for wrong details, The other application was developed using VB.Net and  MySql NOT clssic asp.
I have developed a document management system application using ASP.Net Core 3.1 framework and JWT token authentication. Now I have a requirement to grant current authenticated user an access to another web application which was developed in **VB.Net 2 and  MySqlP** and redirect back to login page (of the Core application) if the user is not authenticated or token has expired.
**Note: Both of these applications are hosted on private network(Intranet).**
After some research I came across the Single-Sing-On concept, passing sessionId in query string etc but not certain to make decision. May I ask whether it is possible to achieve and ways to implement this please?

The code to generate token looks like this

```
 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret_key"));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble("expiryTimeSpan"));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "myIssuer",
            audience: "myIssuer",
            claims : GetUserClaims(user,roles),
            notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: Classic asp can't read asp.net session variables and vice versa.  There are hacks to get around it and a few questions on StackOverflow have covered this.  Here's one for starters
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751398/is-it-possible-to-share-session-state-between-asp-classic-and-asp-net

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link. Sorry there were wrong details in my query, it's now been updated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the flow of obtaining the jwt token? I will assume that you are using OAuth 2.0 or open id connect.

There is a perfectly good guide on the implementation here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Bear in mind that the authorization code is not a session id. It is something to be used once and be exchanged with the access token.

Session ids in url, are very dangerous as they are logged in logs and can be potentially used by others, just by accessing said logs.

Storing the jwt token that openid connect creates in your cookies, is probably the best way to go, if the applications exist in the same domain. Since the idp is the same for all applications, you won't need to authenticate again.

Comment: Thank you Athanasios Kataras for the info. Jfi, this is my first attempt of using Core and JWT authentication...according to my understanding, I am not using OAuth or OpenId connect. Instead using JwtSecurityToken to generate token programmatically and adding it to request header for authorization using 'Bearer' authScheme. Hope this makes sense. Unfortunately, both applications can not be in the same domain.

Comment: What's in your JWT token? Are there claims in it or is it your session id? If the domain is not the same, it's going to be insecure to share it any other way other than the cookie. To do it, you need to implement one of the two protocols (open id is built upon the oauth 2.0) otherwise it can be very easily compromised if it's share over a GET url parameter.

Comment: I have updated the question with JWT code snippet,. It is consist of sub, name, username, JTI, identity claims roles, nbf, expiry, issuer and audience, hope this helps.

Comment: Can the JWT token authentication in one application1(built in Core 3.1) be used to authenticate another application2 (built in VB.net 2) which is hosted under the same domain as application1?  Or would single sign on concept work in this scenario?

Comment: Any solutions to this?